# IntelliJ does not hint available functions/objects on variables

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I have these lines in my code:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class whatever {
    
    @Override
    protected void doPost(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    }
}
```

When I type `StringUtils.` (inside `doPost` function), IntelliJ does not give me hints on the available functions/objects. I know for a fact that there's an object called `StringUtils.EMPTY`.

Perhaps it's a setting I need to set?

Comment: Can you Navigate | Class to `StringUtils` class? Does build | Rebuild Project action work and the `mvn clean compile` from command line?

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by "Navigate | Class" but I can definitely run mvn clean install on my repo. No problems with compiling cute that uses StringUtils.EMPTY. the hinting just didn't work

Comment: Use Navigate | `Class...` action from the Main menu and type `StringUtils`. Does IDE find this class? Does Build | Rebuild Project action work if you use `StringUtils.EMPTY` in code? Attach a sample project to check if possible.